# Disable click event until previous element is been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I really need help with some JavaScript.

[image]
I have created an sample file. I have a table and inside table have an yellow image (see above).

What I want to do with JavaScript is when I click on an image, the red tick appears and the clicked image gets hidden. Also user should click the images in sequence (left to right).

I don't want user to click any random image. He should click the first, than the second, than third and so on. So maybe JavaScript should disables click event all images beside the first. And when user click first image, red tick appears and next image becomes clickable.

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%;" >
 <tr>
<?php 

$count = 1;
for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    ?>
<td><img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="200" height="170"  id="number-<?php echo $count; ?>"></td>
<td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Tick-red.png" width="80" height="60"  id="tick-<?php echo $count; ?>"></td>

<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#tick-<?php echo $count; ?>').hide();
$('#number-<?php echo $count; ?>').click(function(){
    //ajax request
    //**
    //**
    //**

 alert(event.target.id);
    });
});



</script>

<?php
$count++;
}

?>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: what is `event.target.id` and where `event` comes from?

Comment: I given each element with unique ID. `alert(event.target.id);` shows the ID of clicked element.

Comment: Instead of disabling the click event, you could add a check inside the click event so the code only gets executed if the clicked element is the first visible image.

Comment: That would also be fine. I am new to JavaScript so that was the only way I thought off @vi5ion

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable as an index to track what image was clicked.

Using this index you can assign a click handler by calling `target.addEventListener("click", handler)` where target is the element you want to listen for the click event on and `handler` is the code you want to execute.

When the page first loads index will be zero so the first image can get the event handler. In the handler, the image source can be changed and the handler can be removed using `removeEventListener`.

The index can then be incremented and  compared to the number of elements to work through. If the index is less than the number of elements we will take the element at that index and add an event listener to that element. The call back code will be the same resulting in each element being assigned a handler that fires to change the image and bind the next element.

```html
<table id="ticktable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var clickIndex = 0;
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("#ticktable img")[0];
    el.addEventListener("click", onclicked);

    function onclicked(e) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#ticktable img")
        var el = elements[clickIndex++];
        el.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Tick-red.png");
        el.removeEventListener("click", onclicked);
        if (clickIndex < elements.length)
          elements[clickIndex].addEventListener("click", onclicked);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the click event, you could add a check inside the click event so the code only gets executed if the clicked element is the first yellow sign image.

```js
var redTickSrc = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Tick-red.png';

$(function() {
  $('.yellow-sign').on('click',function() {
    var $sign = $(this);
    if ($sign.is($('.yellow-sign').first())) {
      $sign
        .attr('src',redTickSrc)
        .removeClass('yellow-sign')
        .addClass('red-tick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.yellow-sign {
  width: 100px;
}

.red-tick {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have added class named "yellow-sign" to first image of first td. then on click event of yellow-sign, hide curent image and showed second image and added same class on next first image of first td. so, it will work from left to right.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" >
 <tr>
<?php 

$count = 1;
for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    ?>
<td><img src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="200" height="170"  id="number-<?php echo $count; ?>"></td>
<td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Tick-red.png" width="80" height="60"  id="tick-<?php echo $count; ?>" class="tick-red"></td>


<?php
$count++;
}

?>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $('.tick-red').hide();
 $('tr td:first-child').find("img:first-child").addClass("yellow-sign");
 $(document).on("click", ".yellow-sign", function(e){
  var curElement = $(this);
  var number = curElement.attr('id').replace('number-', '');
  var numberpls1 = +number + 1;
  curElement.hide();
  $("#tick-"+ number).show();
  curElement.parent("td").siblings().find("#number-"+ numberpls1).addClass("yellow-sign");
  
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My first answer. :)